# Changing xaml search box from selecting, to filtering results

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Right now, this code works to select a line:

```
<TextBlock Text="Part Number" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBlock}"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Vwr.Table.Tbl, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          DisplayMemberPath="PN" SelectedValuePath="PN"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding Vwr.Table.SelectedRowIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          Text="{Binding Vwr.Table.Vals[1].Val, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          IsEditable="True" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBox}"/>
```

If I type the PN I want to see into the search box, it selects that PN for me. What I'd like to do is change it so that it filters the table results that don't match out.

This is a MVVM system, would I need to build this functionality in the corresponding viewModel as opposed to trying to do it inside of the xaml file?

`Vwr.Table` is our main table, `Vals` is an ObservableCollection. `Vals[0]` is the first col in this table and is our desired value to filter by.

ViewModel
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

```
namespace MDB_N2000
{
    public class MPLViewModel : ModuleViewModel
    {
        public MPLViewModel(string name) : base(name)
        {


            Vwr.Table = new MPLTableViewModel();
            SubVwr.Tables[0] = new PartsListTableViewModel();
            SubVwr.Tables.Add(new OnBOMsTableViewModel());
            SubVwr.Tables.Add(new OnKMRsTableViewModel());
            SubVwr.Tables.Add(new OnOrdersTableViewModel());
            SubVwr.Tables.Add(new HasTravellersTableViewModel());
            SubVwr.Tables.Add(new AssyTreeTableViewModel());
            SubVwr.SelectedTableIndex = 0;

        }

    }
}
```

[ObservableCollection Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDy7u.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your ViewModel looks like, but the following example filters the `ComboBox` values when you type into it. It provides the data to the `ComboBox` via an `ICollectionView`, which has a filter set and is refreshed every time the value in the `ComboBox` changes.

Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private CollectionViewSource _cvs;

    public ICollectionView CVSView { get { return _cvs.View; } }

    private string _partNumberSearchText;
    public string PartNumberSearchText
    {
        get { return _partNumberSearchText; }
        set
        {
            if (_partNumberSearchText != value)
            {
                _partNumberSearchText = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                CVSView.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _coll;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Coll
    {
        get { return _coll; }
        set
        {
            if (_coll != value)
            {
                _coll = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Coll = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "String1",
            "String2",
            "String3"
        };

        _cvs = new CollectionViewSource { Source = Coll };

        CVSView.Filter = ContainsString;
    }

    private bool ContainsString(object obj)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PartNumberSearchText))
            return true;

        if (obj.ToString().ToLower().Contains(PartNumberSearchText.ToLower()))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CVSView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          Text="{Binding PartNumberSearchText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          IsEditable="True" />
```

**UDPATE**

The following is a bit more tailored to your example, e.g., binding to a `DataTable` (in this example, I am displaying the first column (of type `string`) in the `ComboBox`):

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private CollectionViewSource _cvs;

    public ICollectionView CVSView { get { return _cvs.View; } }

    private string _partNumberSearchText;
    public string PartNumberSearchText
    {
        get { return _partNumberSearchText; }
        set
        {
            if (_partNumberSearchText != value)
            {
                _partNumberSearchText = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                RefreshCVSView();
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _cvs = new CollectionViewSource { Source = Vwr.Table.Tbl.Rows };

        CVSView.Filter = ContainsString;
    }

    private void RefreshCVSView()
    {
        if (CVSView.CurrentItem != null)
        {
            DataRow currentItem = (DataRow)CVSView.CurrentItem;

            CVSView.Refresh();

            if (Vwr.Table.Tbl.AsEnumerable().Count(item => item[0] == currentItem[0]) > 0)
                CVSView.MoveCurrentTo(Vwr.Table.Tbl.AsEnumerable().First(item => item[0] == currentItem[0]));
        }
        else
        {
            CVSView.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private bool ContainsString(object obj)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PartNumberSearchText))
            return true;

        DataRow view = obj as DataRow;

        if (view[0].ToString().ToLower().Contains(PartNumberSearchText.ToLower()))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CVSView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          Text="{Binding PartNumberSearchText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          DisplayMemberPath="[0]" IsEditable="True" />
```

`DisplayMemberPath="[0]"` will set the displayed value to the first column in the table.

Using this example, you will have access to the currently selected item via `CVSView`.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to make this work. I posted my ViewModel to see if that gave you a better understanding of the structure. The classes all load data into the tables.

Comment: Could you post more? The main thing I'd need to see is the type of the `ObservableCollection` the `ComboBox` gets its values from. My example uses `ObservableCollection<string>`, so anything around that will need adjusting for your type.

Comment: absolutely, up.

Comment: Ok, I noticed that `Vals` is not in the XAML. What is the type that you're binding to (`Vwr.Table.Tbl`)? Basically, this is the collection that will need to be filtered on the ViewModel.

Comment: Right, Tbl is a dataTable that is filled dynamically with different columns at different times.

So Vwr.Table.Vals[0].Val. would give us the value @ column 1

Comment: I've added another example that uses a `DataTable` as a source. Let me know if it's helpful.